# Setting logback properly in play framework

Tags: scala, logging, playframework, logback

I have an external configuration of logback in file on my filesystem:

```
<configuration>

....

<root level="OFF">
</root>

....

</configuration>
```

I specify the file location with jvm argument: `-Dlogger.file=/path/to/my/file/logger.xml`.

But when I run the tests of the application, first lines, that I see is output from the logger.

`17:42:17,211 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback.groovy]
17:42:17,212 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback-test.xml]
17:42:17,212 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Found resource [logback.xml] at [jar:file:/Users/jakubryska/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe.play/play_2.10/jars/play_2.10-2.2.1.jar!/logback.xml]
17:42:17,228 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.ConfigurationWatchList@307587c - URL [jar:file:/Users/jakubryska/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe.play/play_2.10/jars/play_2.10-2.2.1.jar!/logback.xml] is not of type file
17:42:17,383 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - debug attribute not set
17:42:17,384 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender]
17:42:17,392 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [STDOUT]
17:42:17,412 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA - Assuming default type [ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder] for [encoder] property
17:42:17,467 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.RootLoggerAction - Setting level of ROOT logger to ERROR`

Apparently, I'm doing something in a no good way. I expect no output from the logger. What is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually I've noticed a similar issue with the Play tests themselves, and it seems to all depend on test order execution, and I've never got around to looking into it.  One solution you could use is create a `src/test/resources/application-logger.xml` file, this may or may not suit your end goal.

I do think we need at overhaul of logging configuration in Play, the current situation is quite messy.

Answer (score 0):

Just an FYI, I had these same errors, and the fix turned out to be updating our logback configuration file to match the latest version of Play (See https://playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/SettingsLogger)